# OSX. pytest-xdist error in zsh terminal: zsh: no matches found: 3*popen

Tags: zsh, pytest, xdist

I am using ZSH + iterm as a command line tool. 
When I am trying to run pytest tests with xdist plugin in several subprocesses I get an error: `no matches found: 3*popen`

Execution command: `pytest --tx 3*popen --dist=load`

**Additional info:**

OS version: `OSX 10.13.2`

Pytest: `3.4.0`

Terminal: `Iterm + ZSH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try quoting `*`. For example:

```
pytest --tx 3\*popen --dist=load
```

or

```
pytest --tx '3*popen' --dist=load
```

By default `zsh` prints an error if it cannot match a filename pattern (while `bash` would just leave the pattern unchanged). Quoting glob operators, like `*`, prevents their evaluation, allowing to use them verbatim.

---

It would also be possible to make `zsh` behave like `bash` by disabling the `NOMATCH` option with `setopt no_nomatch`. Personally, I would recommend against it, as it could lead to unexpected results in case there are actually matching file names.